# Best way to use same drawable name for different languages

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-resources

I'm looking for the most efficient way to add a drawable to my project (to show affirmation). Regarding east Asian languages, the symbol to show affirmation is a circle, whereas for everywhere else a check symbol is used.

Is the **current proposal** the best method, or is there a better way to do this?

For the `zh` language code, can I simply use `/drawable-b+zh/affirmation.xml` without having to specify the country code?

**Current proposal**

1. /drawable/affirmation.xml
2. /drawable-b+ja+JA/affirmation.xml
3. /drawable-b+ko+KO/affirmation.xml
4. /drawable-b+mn+MN/affirmation.xml
5. /drawable-b+zh+CN/affirmation.xml
6. /drawable-b+zh+HK/affirmation.xml
7. /drawable-b+zh+MO/affirmation.xml
8. /drawable-b+zh+TW/affirmation.xml

**Desired result (is this possible/allowed)**

1. /drawable/affirmation.xml
2. /drawable-b+ja+JA/affirmation.xml
3. /drawable-b+ko+KO/affirmation.xml
4. /drawable-b+mn+MN/affirmation.xml
5. /drawable-b+zh/affirmation.xml

**Affirmation symbol (East Asia)**

[image]

**Affirmation symbol (elsewhere)**

[image]

**drawable/affirmation.xml (check symbol)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="36sp" android:width="36sp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M21,7L9,19L3.5,13.5L4.91,12.09L9,16.17L19.59,5.59L21,7Z" />
</vector>
```

**drawable/affirmation.xml/ (circle symbol)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="36sp" android:width="36sp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.42,0 -8,-3.58 -8,-8s3.58,-8 8,-8 8,3.58 8,8 -3.58,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: You can specify multiple qualifiers for a single set of resources, separated by dashes. For example, `drawable-en-rUS-land` applies to US-English devices in landscape orientation.

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology You still didn't answer the second question. I read the documentation but can't find anything that helps with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides better way for localization. 
You don't need to put a language code inside a resource name.
Check documentation for more information: [Localize your app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization)